How to use a dev repo to update your sandbox from other stories
Instead of refreshing your developer sandbox every time you work on a new ticket, how can you use a dev repo to update your sandbox so you have the latest code from everyone else too?

This is accomplished with just two simple commands:
git pull
sf project deploy start

This sequence pulls the latest changes from the Git repo, and then deploys detected changes to the Sandbox.
However, you're meant to start each ticket with a new org. It is, quite literally, the recommended best practice. To make it easier to do, salesforce.com introduced Scratch Orgs, which are meant to be used for very short periods of time (less than 30 days). This practice makes sure that you always have a clean org to start from, without having leftover artifacts that can accidentally creep into your repo.

Great. Also how about using VS code UI?

@user149369 The UI has equivalent menu options. Using the Git interface, you can perform pulls, and using the context menus on a file or folder in your SFDX project, you can use the Deploy to Org menu option. You can also set up tasks to make this a single-click operation, and even set up additional steps to deploy sample/test data and/or metadata.
